# Locking Metakit Database in TCL

Tags: locking, ipc, tcl

What is the preferred way to lock a Metakit database from TCL?

Basically I have an application that reads/writes from a Metakit database file, and I'm worried that if the user has two instances of my application running, they could corrupt the database (by doing two writes at the same time).

I know I could use sockets to communicate between instances, but I'd rather not as that could conflict with existing software on the PC. I also thought about using a lock file, but if the process crashes the database would be permanently locked. I know on UNIX it's common to write the PID to a lock file, but I don't know how to tell if a process is still running in a cross platform way. My primary target is Windows.

I'm not totally opposed to adding some native code (compiled C binary), but thought there might be a better pure-TCL way first.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using a lock file is not so unusual; even though database crashing can make the database hard to unlock.  There are some simple workarounds for this issue.

- place the lock in a place that gets cleaned up after a reboot; `/tmp` for unix
- If the application opens and finds that the lock is still open; tell the user what's going on and suggest how to fix it; offer to delete the lock file (after issuing sufficient warning) or tell the user where it is so that they can take the risk of deleting it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The description from the [Metakit page on commits](http://equi4.com/metakit/commit.html) says that there are a number of access modes that can be used to allow multiple readers concurrent with a single writer (probably using locking under the hood). Standard metakit is reasonably careful about not leaving its files in an inconsistent state, so I expect that it will handle all that side of things fairly well. What I don't know is how the features discussed on that page are exposed to Tcl scripts.